# Get internal data from an external server

Tags: networking, security

I don't know if this is the right forum.

Let's say I have an SQL Server on my internal network. Let's also say I have an external web server that's not on the same network but I want it to be able to get information from that internal SQL Server.

How is this done?

I could technically open in the firewall so the external server could communicate with the internal server directly but that doesn't feel secure in case the server gets hacked etc.

I could also make a web service on the internal network that talks to the SQL Server and that the external server can talk to over https, but that also requires me to open up the firewall even if it's just port 443 between the two.

What other solutions are there? Do I set up a second SQL Server on the external network and have some kind of sync of the data? But what if I need the communications to be bidirectional, so that I can change stuff from the external server on the internal database.

And how does bigger companies do this stuff?

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 4):

Set up a VPN between your internal network and the external server. In simple instances, a properly maintained SSH tunnel connection or similar might already be enough.

Comment: yeah that's basically the same as opening up the firewall if the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: No, it's not. A VPN server is meant to secure this kind of connection. Just opening the firewall to your database port is a bad idea, as this is potentially less hardened against malicious connection attempts. And also: You asked how bigger companies do this. VPN is usually the answer.

Comment: How would this be different? If the external server gets hacked they have full access to the internal server any way. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your external server getting hacked is a different threat scenario then securing your exposed database port from the wide internet, which is what you do when spanning a VPN between the networks. Also, you can mitigate this by firewalling off the VPN to only allow the database connection over the VPN and nothing else - having a VPN doesn't mean that the client must have full access to the internal network.

Comment: Yeah but I can accomplish the same thing with configuring the firewall. If I only allow the external servers IP to access the internal server on port 443 I would have basically done the same thing, right? I wouldn't open it up to the entire internet.

Comment: Having a VPN means you have an authenticated and authorized connection between the networks even before connecting to the database. This potentially adds a lot of protection. Again: You asked how this is usually done. This is the way.